# Sending mail from PHP script results in error

Tags: php, email

I have a script that seemed to work before but no longer does.

It is displaying this message after the script runs:

```
Array (
    [0] => Unrouteable address [1] => -All RCPT commands were rejected with this error:\\
    503-Unrouteable address 503 valid RCPT command must precede DATA
)
Array (
    [0] => Unrouteable address [1] => -All RCPT commands were rejected with this error:\\
    503-Unrouteable address 503 valid RCPT command must precede DATA
)
Array (
    [0] => Unrouteable address [1] => -All RCPT commands were rejected with this error:\\
    503-Unrouteable address 503 valid RCPT command must precede DATA
)
```

The actual function:

```
function emailUser($table, $subject, $message) {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM $table";
    $result=mysql_query($query);

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $i = 0;

        while($i <= 0) {
            $to = $row['email'];
            $to_all .= '<li>'.$row['email'].'</li>';
            $mail = new htmlMimeMail();
            $mail->setHTML($message);
            $mail->setSubject($subject);
            $mail->setSMTPParams('mail.site.net', 25, 'site.net');
            $mail->setReturnPath("email@site.net");
            $mail->setFrom("email@site.net");

            $mail_result = $mail->send(array($to), 'smtp');

            if (!$mail_result) {
                    print_r($mail->errors);
                    //failure
                } else {
                    //success
                }
            $i++;
        }
    }
    print '<h3>Mail successuly sent to:</h3>';
    print '<ul>'.$to_all.'</ul>';
}
```

Is there a better script to use? Maybe the email server has changed?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind is to check the validity of the email address. However, above and beyond this, what is the purpose of the inner while loop ("$i <=0") - it seems completely spurious and that loop will only execute once anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reordering to the following (setHTML is at the end):

```
$mail->setSubject($subject);
$mail->setSMTPParams('mail.site.net', 25, 'site.net');
$mail->setReturnPath("email@site.net");
$mail->setFrom("email@site.net");
$mail->setHTML($message);
```

Comment: that did the job. But I did receive a timeout error, but the emails went thru. Maybe I should go about sending a mass email better.

Comment: Interesting. I find it strange that the order of arguments would cause a problem.

I've used/currently use PEAR:Mail and it's worked out quite well for me.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that $row['email'] is the correct column?

The error seems to indicate to me that the recipient list that the function is receiving is suspect.

Answer (score 0):

what is this htmlMimeMail class that you're using? did you write it yourself?

This is a good mail sender library for PHP: [SwiftMailer](http://www.swiftmailer.org/)

As for the reason why it used to work and now it doesn't, it's probable that the mail server configuration changed. Is it your mail server? Or is it your ISP's? I suspect that it changed its behaviour due to some spam prevention mechanism. It might be rejecting the SMTP RCPT recipients because, say, you haven't logged in first using some means (like POP before SMTP, or authenticated SMTP).